# How do I pass objects and/or multi-dimensional arrays from Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a post submission using XMLHttpRequest, but am having a hard time passing the values to PHP in an efficient way.

Comment: What's wrong with http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ ?

Comment: I suppose there is nothing wrong with it.  I am just not using Jquery.  I was looking for a way to simulate the way a form can build multi-dimensional data and submit it.  I thought I could do this without using JSON.

Comment: While it could be useful for learning, in practice it's rare that a live site or web app makes raw XMLHttpRequests.  You will have a much easier time using a library like jQuery, which as Cyclone points out gives you the added benefit of form serializing.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your name is probably kind of your answer is quite hilarious. Meaning: JSON serialization is a very good way of passing arrays between js and PHP. There are native json functions in PHP since version 5.2.

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So I've tried using json_decode; but I am having problems with getting the data to PHP correctly.  On the Javascript side, I've used JSON.stringify on the data.  I have the AJAX request set to use POST, But I can't seem to access the info in $_POST correctly.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use some existing library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), then you don't need to write your own client, waste time supporting different browsers, etc. Its much easier than writing yourself everything from scratch (unless you want to learn it)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest passing your data using JSON format, and `application/json` MIME type. I'm sure there are libraries in PHP for parsing JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery does indeed make this easy.  It actually opens up a few methods to get your data there.

If your data populates a HTML form you could use Jquery to programmatically submit data back to the server via the POST route.

Alternatively you can also set up AJAX calls that use either GET or POST requests, or as these other chaps suggest, you could serialize your data into JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)  and submit it that way.